# /tmp/ccGzk7jP.s: Fatal error: can't close testWriter.o: No space left on device while installing rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

I am very new to all the concepts I am trying to learn, so any help or direction is appreciated.

I am trying to install rails on Ubuntu virtual machine and getting the following error:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:/media/ubuntu/49fa903b-331f-4c8f-862b-64745bd574f3$ gem install rails
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20170501-7896-19qanuj.rb extconf.rb
checking if the C compiler accepts ... yes
Building nokogiri using packaged libraries.
Using mini_portile version 2.1.0
checking for gzdopen() in -lz... yes
checking for iconv... yes
************************************************************************
IMPORTANT NOTICE:

Building Nokogiri with a packaged version of libxml2-2.9.4
with the following patches applied:
    - 0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch
    - 0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch
    - 0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch

Team Nokogiri will keep on doing their best to provide security
updates in a timely manner, but if this is a concern for you and want
to use the system library instead; abort this installation process and
reinstall nokogiri as follows:

    gem install nokogiri -- --use-system-libraries
        [--with-xml2-config=/path/to/xml2-config]
        [--with-xslt-config=/path/to/xslt-config]

If you are using Bundler, tell it to use the option:

    bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries
    bundle install

Note, however, that nokogiri is not fully compatible with arbitrary
versions of libxml2 provided by OS/package vendors.
************************************************************************
Extracting libxml2-2.9.4.tar.gz into tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4... OK
Running git apply with /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0001-Fix-comparison-with-root-node-in-xmlXPathCmpNodes.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0002-Fix-XPointer-paths-beginning-with-range-to.patch... OK
Running git apply with /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/patches/libxml2/0003-Disallow-namespace-nodes-in-XPointer-ranges.patch... OK
Running 'configure' for libxml2 2.9.4... OK
Running 'compile' for libxml2 2.9.4... ERROR, review '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/compile.log' to see what happened. Last lines are:
========================================================================
  CC       reader2.o
  CCLD     reader2
  CC       reader3.o
  CCLD     reader3
  CC       reader4.o
  CCLD     reader4
  CC       testWriter.o
/tmp/ccGzk7jP.s: Assembler messages:
/tmp/ccGzk7jP.s: Fatal error: can't close testWriter.o: No space left on device
Makefile:687: recipe for target 'testWriter.o' failed
make[3]: *** [testWriter.o] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/libxml2-2.9.4/doc/examples'
Makefile:779: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/libxml2-2.9.4/doc'
Makefile:1440: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1/ext/nokogiri/tmp/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/ports/libxml2/2.9.4/libxml2-2.9.4'
Makefile:859: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
========================================================================
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    --with-opt-dir
    --without-opt-dir
    --with-opt-include
    --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
    --with-opt-lib
    --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
    --with-make-prog
    --without-make-prog
    --srcdir=.
    --curdir
    --ruby=/home/ubuntu/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.3/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
    --help
    --clean
    --use-system-libraries
    --enable-static
    --disable-static
    --with-zlib-dir
    --without-zlib-dir
    --with-zlib-include
    --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
    --with-zlib-lib
    --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
    --enable-cross-build
    --disable-cross-build
/home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:366:in `block in execute': Failed to complete compile task (RuntimeError)
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `chdir'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:337:in `execute'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:111:in `compile'
    from /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/mini_portile2-2.1.0/lib/mini_portile2/mini_portile.rb:150:in `cook'
    from extconf.rb:364:in `block (2 levels) in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:257:in `block in chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir'
    from extconf.rb:256:in `chdir_for_build'
    from extconf.rb:363:in `block in process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `tap'
    from extconf.rb:262:in `process_recipe'
    from extconf.rb:547:in `<main>'

To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log which can be found here:

  /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/mkmf.log

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/nokogiri-1.7.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/ubuntu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.3.0/nokogiri-1.7.1/gem_make.out
```

My understanding is that I am out of space and the installation fails. I tried installing other programs and it failed with the same error.
But It looks to me that I have enough space allocated and there should not be any problems with partition.

Screenshots Below

[gparted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FP39Y.png)

[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKqc5.png)